# Why does getchar() only return (char)13 after another key has been pressed? (windows)

Tags: c, windows, winapi, windows-console

I was playing around with the Windows Console API and found some interesting behaviour. Using this function:

```c
void defConsole() {
    HANDLE hStdIn = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    DWORD mode = 0;

    GetConsoleMode(hStdIn, &mode);

    SetConsoleMode(hStdIn, mode & ~(ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT | ENABLE_LINE_INPUT));
}
```

I was able to make it so that the terminal behaves like non-canonical *nix terminals. (Getchar does not wait for enter and doesn't display what you write, like conio.h's getch or unistd.h's getpass). I then tried printing each character written along with its ascii(?) value.

```c
int main() {
    char c;
    defConsole();

    while (1) {
        c = getchar();
        printf("%c %d\n", c, (int)c);
    }
}
```

However, something interesting happened: When I pressed enter, nothing happened, but the next key I pressed would be overriden by it (ascii code 13), and the next key would print both the last one and itself.

Why does this happen? What can I do to stop this? Should I change it to use winapi's keyboard input functions instead? That seems like an overkill to me.

Comment: Is it possible that printing enter with %c is messing up the printing? Does it still work this way if you just print the ascii codes?

Comment: @user253751 It still does

Answer (score 2):

To conform with C's line-ending standards, `\r\n` must be replaced with `\n`.  But you can't know if the sequence is `\r\n` until you get the character after the `\r`, so it must be buffered until the next character comes in.  Try typing `Ctrl-J` (`\n`) after the `Enter` to see what happens.

Comment: Pressing Ctrl-J does nothing. I tried ungetc('\n') if c == '\r' and the same thing happened (except this time the \n did get printed)

Comment: When I press enter, only \r ((char)13) gets printed; (char)10 does not.

Comment: @Dawniam that's interesting, I expected the 13 to get dropped and only the 10 to get through.